# Always "requiring unknown module" when reading json file

Tags: react-native

bit of an RN newb here. I'm trying to read some json data files:

```
function loadCategories() {
  const ids = ['tl1', 'tl2', 'tl3', 'tl4', 'tl5', 'tl6'];
  ids.forEach(function(id) {
    var contents = require('../Content/top-level/' + id + ".json.js");
    ...
  });
}
```

But here I always get an error:

> Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring unknown module "../Content/top-level/tl1.json.js".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install".

The files exist and my relative path logic should be OK given the project structure:

```
ProjectDir
  Components
    ThisComponent.js
  Content
    top-level
      tl1.json.js
      tl2.json.js
      ...
```

i.e. the above code is running from `ThisComponent.js` and trying to access `tl1.json.js`, etc so I would think the relative path of `../Content/top-level/tl1.json.js` would work.

I've tried:

- Restarting the packager
- Referencing `./Content/top-level/tl1.json.js` instead
- Referencing `/Content/top-level/tl1.json.js` instead

I'm on RN 0.36.0. Gotta be something obvious…right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible in React Native because of how the packager works. You have to require files with static string path. You can use a switch statement something like this -

```
switch (id) {
  case 'tl1': return require('../Content/top-level/tl1.json');
  case 'tl2': return require('../Content/top-level/tl2.json');
  ...
}
```

Also why does your json files have `.js` extension?

Comment: I have a sample RN app that does exactly this and works. Did they remove the ability to do this in some later version? The `.js` was just me troubleshooting in case the packager only found files ending in .js or something.

Comment: Not sure if it worked before. Look at this issue created exactly an year ago https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3882

Comment: Looks like react-native-fs might be an option. https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs